# concept checker doesn't compile on gcc because it 'has no linkage'

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++-concepts

I've created a concept checking class based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927032/sfinae-check-for-static-member-using-decltype) whose purpose is to make sure a given class has a static member function called `baseUnitConversionFactor`. The class compiles and works fine with msvc2013, but it wont compile on gcc 4.9.2 (using -std=c++14) with the error:

> error: *‘{anonymous}::UnitsTest_conceptChecker_Test::TestBody()::validUnit::baseUnitConversionFactor’* 
>   is not a valid template argument for type ‘double (*)()’ because 
>   *‘static double {anonymous}::UnitsTest_conceptChecker_Test::TestBody()::validUnit::baseUnitConversionFactor()’* 
>   has no linkage
>
> static std::true_type test(tester<&U::baseUnitConversionFactor>*);

I don't really know what that means, and am much more familiar with writing templates in visual studios (obviously) much more permisive enviornment. Can anyone help figure out what I need to do to fix this?

**Concept Checker Class**

```
template <typename T>
struct has_baseUnitConversionFactor
{
    template<double(*)()> struct tester;

    template<typename U>
    static std::true_type test(tester<&U::baseUnitConversionFactor>*);
    template<typename U>
    static std::false_type test(...);

    static const bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
};
```

**Test which I think causes the error**

```
TEST_F(UnitsTest, conceptChecker)
{
    struct validUnit
    {
        static inline double baseUnitConversionFactor() { return 0.0; }
        typedef void unit_category;
        typedef void base_unit_type;
    };

    EXPECT_TRUE(has_baseUnitConversionFactor<validUnit>::value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 and C++14, pointer/reference template arguments must refer to entities with linkage (in C++03, they were limited to entities with external linkage). A local class has no linkage, and neither do its member functions.

This restriction has been removed in C++17 by [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html), and GCC trunk claims to have implemented that paper, but apparently not the linkage part.

Sidestepping this issue requires not using `&U::baseUnitConversionFactor` as a template non-type argument. Happily, a much simpler way to test that the expression `T::baseUnitConversionFactor()` is valid and returns exactly `double` is:

```
template <typename T, class=double>
struct has_baseUnitConversionFactor : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct has_baseUnitConversionFactor<T, decltype(T::baseUnitConversionFactor())>
         : std::true_type { };
```

This does depend on expression SFINAE (but then, so does the original), so I'm not sure if it will work on MSVC 2013.

For a more general check, you may want to look at [`std::experimental::is_detected_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected). That cppreference page has a reference implementation.

Comment: does your example ensure that `baseUnitConversionFactor` is static?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus If it isn't static, `T::baseUnitConversionFactor()` isn't a valid expression.

Comment: can this construct also be used if I wanted to check for a non-static member function?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Sure, you want something along the lines of `decltype(std::declval<T&>().nonstaticmemberfunction())`.

Comment: for reference of others who may want to use this, msvc2013 does not support expression SFINAE, which this construct requires, and so it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, the problem seems to be caused by the way gtest uses anonymous namespaces. Moving the `validUnit` declaration into the test fixture (called UnitsTest) and changing the EXPECT statement to use the fixture namespace solved the issue.

**Updated Fixture**

```
class UnitsTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:

    UnitsTest()
    {

    }

    virtual ~UnitsTest()
    {

    }

    virtual void SetUp()
    {

    }

    virtual void TearDown()
    {

    }

    struct validUnit
    {
        static inline double baseUnitConversionFactor() { return 0.0; }
        typedef void unit_category;
        typedef void base_unit_type;
    };
};
```

**Updated Test**

```
TEST_F(UnitsTest, conceptChecker)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(has_baseUnitConversionFactor<UnitsTest::validUnit>::value);
}
```