# error with decltype template with msvc2013

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, sfinae, decltype

I'm trying to use the following construct to check for the existence of a member function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501232/concept-checker-doesnt-compile-on-gcc-because-it-has-no-linkage/34501564?noredirect=1#comment56765720_34501564) that I previously got:

```
template <typename T, class = double>
struct has_a : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_a<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().a())> : std::true_type {};
```

This works fine with gcc 4.9.2, but fails to compile with msvc2013:

> error C2228: left of '.a' must have class/struct/union type is
>   'add_rvalue_reference<_Ty>::type'

It seems(?) like this is a compiler bug, since `declval` is specifically supposed to work within an unevaluated `decltype` expression [(see here)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/declval/). Is there a known workaround?

Comment: This relies on [expression SFINAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae#12654277), but MSVC2013 [doesn't support it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) (although I understand that they have some expression SFINAE features ready for the next version).

Comment: @TartanLlama that's what I was worried about. Is there a similar idiom that doesn't break visual studio?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus [try this](http://rextester.com/BMCKE70673)

Comment: Have you look at the different "check-if-class-has-function" as [check-if-class-has-function-with-signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975147/check-if-class-has-function-with-signature/24976592#24976592). there are variants which should work also for c++03

Comment: As far as I can tell, MSVC2013 seems to have some support for expression SFINAE in function template return types (they use it in their `allocator_traits` and `is_assignable`). Can you try [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2192109aa09f933)?

Comment: @T.C. thanks, I was reading the same thing, and your sample helped me get to the answer. The actual solution is a tad lass verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC 2013's trailing return type parser appears to be more complete than the expression SFINAE system, and if the checker is refactored the following way ([following T.C's suggestion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2192109aa09f933)), it works as expected on both msvc2013 and gcc 4.9.2:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_a_impl
{
    template<typename U>
    static auto test(U* p) -> decltype(p->a()); // checks function existence
    template<typename U>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

    using type = typename std::is_floating_point<decltype(test<T>(0))>::type; // checks return type is some kind of floating point
};

template <typename T>
struct has_a : has_a_impl<T>::type {};
```

An added benefit of this syntax is the return type check can use any of the `type_traits`, so you don't have to check for a single type of return value (e.g. double).